# cannot send a content-copy with this verb type

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from json ('.cfm') file. I tried different solutions and still unable to fix the error. I found a solution on stack over flow about using XMLReader, but does that work when reading data from json file? I also tried to use HttpClient.GetAsync() method with the same result.

According to the API document, caller must set a header “Authorization” to the value of an agreed upon token. The web service has one required parameter. The method of access is via GET request. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw5Yh.png) of my code in c#.

> Uri with parameters: https://www.aopa.org/webservices/USAlliance/api.cfm?customerId=10180072

I also tried getting the result with jquery ajax call, which is as follows: (here I tried putting latest jquery library as 'src' value, secondly, instead of 'complete' I tried 'success' variable, then I found 'done' function on internet, that also did not work out)

```
function btn_p1_clientFunction() {
     console.log("btn_p1_clientFunction is called!");
     javascript: window.scrollTo(0, 0);

     var token = 'USA11!anc3';
     var memberID = $('#txtAOPAMemberNum').val();
     var client = "https://www.aopa.org/webservices/USAlliance/api.cfm?customerId=" + memberID;

     $.ajax({
         url: 'https://www.aopa.org/webservices/USAlliance/api.cfm',
         headers: { 'Authorization': token },
         data: {
             "message": $(this).val(),
             "status": $(this).val(),
             "master_customer_id": $(this).val(),
             "member": $(this).val(),
         },
         complete: function () {
             alert(this.headers.Authorization);
         }
     });

     $.get(client, function (data, status) {
         alert("Message: " + data.message + "\nStatus: " + data.status + "\nMember ID: " + data.master_customer_id + "\nMember: " + data.member);
     });
     }
```

The alert displaying header 'Authorization', gives correct value. The output alert displaying data object from json (cfm) file, is producing unwanted results.

> Message: Authorization missing or invalid.
>
> Status: ERROR
>
> Member ID: undefined
>
> Member: undefined

Also, when tested in Postman, output is what I want. After which I'm sure, something is wrong in my way of programming.

```
{
   "message": "",
   "status": "OK",
   "master_customer_id": 10180072,
   "member": true
}
```

Please, help me in resolving the issue. I have been trying both ways (c# and jquery) since weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You Authorization should be in format of:

```
'Authorization':'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Please do check if token value follows the format

Answer (score 0):

@praty The solution didn't work out. However, I tried removing the data variable block and XMLReader commands and now its working as required. [Working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtaMt.png)